# Rename directory with constantly changing name

Tags: python, arcpy

I created a script that is supposed to download some data, then run a few processes. The data source (being ArcGIS Online) always downloads the data as a zip file and when extracted the folder name will be a series of letters and numbers. I noticed that these occasionally change (not entirely sure why). My thought is to run an os.listdir to get the folder name then rename it. Where I run into issues is that the list returns the folder name with brackets and quotes. It returns as ['f29a52b8908242f5b1f32c58b74c063b.gdb'] as the folder name while folder in the file explorer does not have the brackets and quotes. Below is my code and the error I receive.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

file_name = "THDNuclearFacilitiesBaseSandboxData.zip"

with ZipFile(file_name) as zip:
    # unzipping all the files
    print("Unzipping "+ file_name)
    zip.extractall("C:/NAPSG/PROJECTS/DHS/THD_Nuclear_Facilities/SCRIPT/CountyDownload/Data")

    print('Unzip Complete')

#removes old zip file
os.remove(file_name)


x = os.listdir("C:/NAPSG/PROJECTS/DHS/THD_Nuclear_Facilities/SCRIPT/CountyDownload/Data")
os.renames(str(x), "Test.gdb")
```

Output:

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: "['f29a52b8908242f5b1f32c58b74c063b.gdb']" -> 'Test.gdb'

I'm relatively new to python scripting, so if there is an easier alternative, that would be great as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.listdir()` returns a list files/objects that are in a folder.

`lists` are represented, when printed to the screen, using a set of brackets.
The name of each file is a `string` of characters and `strings` are represented, when printed to the screen, using quotes.

So we are seeing a `list` with a single filename:

```
['f29a52b8908242f5b1f32c58b74c063b.gdb']
```

To access an item within a `list` using Python, you can using index notation (which happens to also use brackets to tell Python which item in the `list` to use by referencing the index or number of the item.

Python `list` indexes starting at zero, so to get the first (and in this case only item in the `list`), you can use `x[0]`.

```
x = os.listdir("C:/NAPSG/PROJECTS/DHS/THD_Nuclear_Facilities/SCRIPT/CountyDownload/Data")
os.renames(x[0], "Test.gdb")
```

Having said that, I would generally not use `x` as a variable name in this case... I might write the code a bit differently:

```
files = os.listdir("C:/NAPSG/PROJECTS/DHS/THD_Nuclear_Facilities/SCRIPT/CountyDownload/Data")
os.renames(files[0], "Test.gdb")
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked great. And yeah, I know x is a bad variable name, just had something simple for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets indicate a list. Try x[0] that should get rid of the brackets and be just the data.
The return from listdir may be a list with only one value or a whole bunch